# Copy/paste values every day under previous pasted cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's my problem : i'm trying to copy a value from one cell in "sheet1" to another cell in "sheet2".
But I want to run this script everyday (using trigger) because the value change every day. So the paste has to be in B2 the first day, B3 the second day, etc. I want to be able to follow the value day by day and have an historic.

Here's my current script :

```
function backup(){

  var sourceSheet  = "Portfolio" ;
    var sourceRange = "N15" ;
  var targetSheet = "Suivi perfs journalières" ;
    var targetRange = "B2:B999" ;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var values = sheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(targetRange).setValues(values);
```

I have 2 problem :

1. My script send me this error : *Exception: The number of rows of data does not match the number of rows in the range. There are 1 lines of data, but the range has 998. (line 12, "CopyPastePortfolioValue" file)*
2. I don't know how to paste the value in a new cell everyday (paste in the cell under the previous each day)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value from the cell `N15` in the source sheet and append the value to the target sheet.

#### Modification points:

- When `setValues(values)` is used, the lengths of rows and columns of `values` are required to match to the range. In your script, `values` of `var values = sheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValues();` is 1 row and 1 column. But the target range is `B2:B999`. By this, such error occurs. I think that this is the answer for your 1st question.
- In order to append the value to the target sheet, in your case, I would like to propose to use `appendRow`. I think that this is the answer for your 2nd question.
- And, when a value from a cell, you can also use `getValue` instead of `getValues`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function backup(){
  var sourceSheet  = "Portfolio";
  var sourceRange = "N15";
  var targetSheet = "Suivi perfs journalières";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var value = sheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValue();  // Modified
  ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).appendRow([value]);  // Modified
}
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Hey Tanaike ! 

Thanks for your help. 
I understand why it is a good idea to use appendRow, when I run your modified script, that doesn't add a row, and it doesn't paste the value neither.

Comment: @Demeterro Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I understand why it is a good idea to use appendRow, when I run your modified script, that doesn't add a row, and it doesn't paste the value neither.`. In order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And also, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.